# Table with rowspan, <td> heights incorrect in Safari (7.1.2), fine in FF/IE/Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've got a basic HTML table that uses rowspan.

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table, tr, td{
    border:1px solid #f00;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>top image</td>
    <td rowspan="2">text<br />text<br />text<br />text<br />text<br />text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>bottom image</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>top image</td>
    <td rowspan="2">text<br />text<br />text<br />text<br />text<br />text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>bottom image</td>
</tr>
```

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/38ro2p39/1/

In Firefox (36), Chrome (40) and IE10 it looks like I'd expect that the "Top Image" and "Bottom Image" cells are of even size.

In Safari (5.1.7 for Windows) the "Top Image" cell is the height of it's content, and "Bottom Image" fills the rest of the space.

I don't want to specify any sizes for rows/columns as the content changes size and needs to stretch.

Any ideas why this happens, or how I can get around it?
Thanks!

PS. I'm up for alternatives to tables. I did look at using `<div>` with table-layout but it lacks rowspan.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Pete for pointing out Safari for Windows is ancient. A friend using Safari 7.1.2 for Mac OSX confirms the issue still occurs in that version.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I didn't realise it was that old. I guess I'll have to find someone with a Mac so I can see if my site renders correctly.

Comment: Updated question to reflect that the issue still occurs in Safari 7.1.2 for Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **[spec](http://quia.cf/orange/pooxy4/nph-poxy.pl/es/20/http/www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout)**:

> CSS 2.1 does not specify how cells that span more than one row affect row height calculations except that the sum of the row heights involved must be great enough to encompass the cell spanning the rows.

I can't find a CSS method of fixing this, but I've come up with a JavaScript method, which works for your code:

```
var td= document.querySelectorAll('tr td[rowspan="2"]');

for(var i = 0 ; i < td.length ; i++) {
  if(Math.abs(td[i].offsetHeight/2 - td[i].parentNode.children[0].offsetHeight) > 1) {
    td[i].parentNode.children[0].style.height = td[i].offsetHeight/2 + 'px';
  }
}
```

Basically, it gets all `td`s having a rowspan, and it sets the other `td` in their row to be half their height.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/79gcgbxd/)

Comment: It works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox now, but in IE10 it just reversed the problem.

Comment: Interesting!  I've now updated the answer to change the height only if needed.  Try now.